# Sending images blob data to a server with multipart/form-data

Tags: react-native, next.js13

I've been dealing with this for far too long. Here is what I want to do:

Get an image using expo's ImagePicker (done).

Convert it to a blob (I think did this one as well, but still might be the cause of the issue).

Send it as a blob to my server.

This shouldn't be complicated in my opinion. I managed to do this with curl and everything works great!. Here is the code:

```
curl <myurl> \
     -X POST \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" \
     -F "image=@path/to/image1.png" \
     -F "image=@path/to/image2.png"
```

Now, doing this from my app gives different issues depending on what I try:

**Atempt 1**

```
// assume I already got the all uris I want to send to my server.
async function upload() {
    const formData = new FormData()
    const uriResult = await fetch(uri1)
    const blob = await uriResult.blob()
    formData.append("image", blob, image1.jpeg)   // assume the image is a JPEG

    try {
        const apiResponse = await fetch(
            serverUrl,   // variable was created somewehere else
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            },
            body: formData,
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

This attempt will cause an error on my server that states: `Multipart: Boundary not found`.

**Attempt 2**

I read somewhere online that by assigning manually the "Content-Type" header to "multipart/form-data" without providing a boundary, will cause the previous error. So I tried removing it. Then after running the previous code (without the headers part) my server was unable to retrieve any image.

Note that the way I'm getting all images is:

```
const formData = await request.formData();
const files = formData.getAll("image") as Blob[] | null;
```

Is there a way to this properly? Also, I want to use only the fetch API, so external libraries like axios should be out of question (unless there is something about the fetch API that makes the entire operation impossible to do with it, which seems very unlikely).

Thanks!

Comment: Well, what I wanted to do in the first place was sending images to my server, so it can then upload them to an aws s3 bucket. Since I didn't find any "standard" way to do this I went with the form data way. Are there better options?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but you don't need to send the image as blob.
Given you already have the image URI, this is a simple as :

```
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('file', {
      uri: imageUrl,
      name: 'toto.jpg',
      type: 'image/jpeg',
  })


  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  });
```

Comment: Two things about this approach:
1. Every time I attempt this, I get a typescript error saying that the object containing the image information is not a blob nor a string. 
2. What should the server expect if not a form?

Comment: Also, would you go with another way of handling image (or general media) if you intended to uploading them to an aws s3 bucket?

Comment: I've searched the internet and cannot find a way to cast the object of uri/name/type to a File. just use `as any` as a dirty no type solution :/ 

But using AWS S3 is a different issue though, and this library may help you: https://github.com/benjreinhart/react-native-aws3/tree/master

Comment: I see. One of the reasons I hate typescript (but I can't avoid using it). Do you think is a good idea to use the library you suggested? I don't like the idea of having the credentials of an IAM user in my client. Even using environment variables in expo is not recommended (source: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/) when dealing when sensitive information.

Comment: I won't use the library, but being open source mean you can find solution (= explorer the source code) to use AWS S3 without using the official AWS library.

Comment: After trying your approach posted above, I got an error (Multipart: Boundary not found).

Comment: I went with a different approach. Just sending the image as a request body. Seems easier and doesn't deteriorate my mental health :). If someone finds a fix, please share it.

Comment: Post an answer to your question and accept it !

Answer (score 0):

Although not a real answer to what I was trying to do, I changed my approach and decided to send images as a request body. This is what I did:

```
// Assume uri is the uri of the image selected with Expo's ImagePicker.

async function uploadImage(uri: string) {
    const result = await fetch(uri)
    const blob = await result.blob()
    const b64 = (await blobToB64(blob)) as string
    
    // Should wrap the following in a try/catch statement.
    const response = await fetch(
        serverUri,
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: { image: b64 }
        }
}

function blobToBase64(blob: Blob) {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.onload = () => {
            resolve(String(reader?.result).split(",")[1])
        }
    })
}
```

You don't have to encode it as base64, though